# Reload Elasticsearch index data from DynamoDB using Kenesis Firehouse and Lambda

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm using Lambda to send DynamoDB Streams to Kenesis Firehouse and then to Elasticsearch.

I would like to know if it's possible to reload Elasticsearch index data from DynamoDB automatically. I mean, If I delete de elasticsearch Index data. How to send again the old one without using any lambda script.

In the `view type` of DynamoDB I have selected `New and old images`. I don't know if it's related. Because some times I receive in the elasticsearch  records an attribute called `OldImage` or `NewImage` that contains the data coming from DynamoDB.

Comment: Can't you use logstash dynamoDB input plugin ?

Comment: @MohammadMazraeh If it's necessary I would consider to use it